# Отсортировать и удалить слова из предложения в строке символов

Tags: c, строки, указатели

В програме пользователь вводит предложение и ключевое слово, а програма должна напечатать все слова введеного предложения, не содержащие букв, из которых состоит ключевое слово, или вывести сообщение об отсутствии таких слов. Уже который день сижу над вроде-бы простой задачкой, но дедлайн поджимает, потому и решил обратиться за помощью

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вводим ключевое слово и размещаем его в массиве символов char key_w[16];
2. Вводим предложение в строку
3. Строку разбиваем на слова с помощью функции strtok (http://all-ht.ru/inf/prog/c/func/strtok.html)
4. Получаемые слова размещаем в массиве char *wrd[100];
5. В цикле перебираем все полученные слова
6. Внутри этого цикла перебираем в цикле все символы ключевого слова
7. Проверяем наличие символов в слове с помощью функци *index()*
8. Если буква найдена - сразу переходим к следующему слову
9. Если ни одной буквы не найдено - печатаем слово